# Earliest example of older male author being flattered by female fan, breaking relationship after discovering she confused him with famous namesake

Tags: history-of-literature

I'm sure I have seen this theme in literature or film more than once:

An older male author is flattered by a young, female student, after she says she loves his books.  They start a relationship.  One morning, he asks her what book of his she likes most.  When she names a title, he realises that it is not his books she admires, but the books by a more famous author with the same family name.  He is heartbroken, his ego thrashed, and he throws out the girl he suddenly considers terribly stupid.

**When and where and by who was this theme first described?**

I saw this most recently in the film *Elle* by Paul Verhoeven, based on the novel *Oh...* by Philippe Djian.  I'm certain I've encountered the theme before and neither Djian nor Verhoeven was the first to describe it.

Comment: I doubt this actually happened to [the other Winston Churchill](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Winston_Churchill_(novelist)), but one can dream.